# How can I remove all non alpha numeric characters in head and tail of words using the delimiter?

Tags: java, arrays, delimiter, cpu-word

I want to print a list of words which I receive via a document using the scanner. The file contains a piece of a book, for example:

```
'Oh, I BEG your pardon!' she exclaimed in a tone of great dismay, and
began picking them up again as quickly as she could, for the accident of
the goldfish kept running in her head, and she had a vague sort of idea
that they must be collected at once and put back into the jury-box, or
they would die.
```

For an assignment I have to use the delimiter, so I need to form a pattern. I want to remove all te non-alphanumeric characters at the head and tail of the words. How should I implement the correct pattern?

I think it should be something with [^a-zA-Z0-9], but I need to assign this to the head and tail of the words

This simply removes all the wrong characters, so also in middle of words which is not what I need:

```
Scanner string=openTextFile(fileName).useDelimiter([^a-zA-Z0-9]);
```

---

Here is my code. This question is about the content command in the switch.

```
 package nl.ru.ai.SjoerdSam.exercise7;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Concordances
{

  final static int MAX_NR_OF_WORDS=20000;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    try
    {
      String[] words=new String[MAX_NR_OF_WORDS];
      int[] freqs=new int[MAX_NR_OF_WORDS];
      boolean terminate=true;
      while(terminate)
      {
        System.out.println("Please enter 'read' to start reading a file and display number of words read, "+"'content' to display content (all currently stored words in the order of apperance), "+"'stop' to stop the program or "+"'count'+ the word you want to count to count the number of occurences of a word, "+"the total number of words and the percantage of occurences. Followed by the filename.");
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput=input.nextLine();
        String command=assignTask(userInput);
        String fileName=assignFilename(userInput);
        Scanner string=openTextFile(fileName).useDelimiter("\\s|\\W(?=\\s)|(?<=\\s)\\W|^\\W|\\W$|!");

        switch(command)
        {
          case "read":
            FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line=bufferedReader.readLine();

            int allWords=0;

            while(line!=null)
            {
              String[] wordsInLine=line.split(" ");
              allWords=allWords+wordsInLine.length;
              line=bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println("The number of words in this file is: "+allWords+"\n");
            break;
          case "content":
            int nr=findAndCountWords(string,words,freqs);
            displayWords(nr,words,freqs);
            break;
          case "stop":
            terminate=false;
            System.out.println("Program terminated");
            break;
          //            case "count":
          //// Bit stuck here on how to do the count and show the frequency of a single word. if i would actually get the frequency the percentage could be found by dividing the frequency with total number of words found above
          //              Scanner single=new Scanner(System.in);
          //              System.out.println("Please type in the word you want to know data of");
          //              String word= single.nextLine();
          //              findAndCountWord(scanner,words,word);
          //              System.out.println("The frequency for the word"+" "+ single +" "+"is" + findAndCountWord(single,words,word) );
          //              break;

        }
      }
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
      System.out.print(e);
    }
  }

  private static String assignFilename(String input)
  {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<input.length();i++)
      if(input.charAt(i)==' '||input==null)
        break;
    input=input.substring(i+1,input.length());
    return input;
  }

  private static String assignTask(String input)
  {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<input.length();i++)
      if(input.charAt(i)==' ')
        break;
    input=input.substring(0,i);
    return input;
  }

  static Scanner openTextFile(String input) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    assert (true);
    FileInputStream fileName=new FileInputStream(input);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileName));
    return new Scanner(bufferedReader);
  }
  static int findAndCountWords(Scanner scanner, String[] words, int[] freqs)
  {
    assert words!=null&&freqs!=null;
    int nr=0;
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
      String word=scanner.next();
      if(updateWord(word,words,freqs,nr))
        nr++;
    }
    return nr;
  }

  static boolean updateWord(String word, String[] words, int[] freqs, int nr)
  {
    assert nr>=0&&words!=null&&freqs!=null;
    int pos=sequentialSearch(words,0,nr,word);
    if(pos<nr)
    {
      freqs[pos]++;
      return false;
    } else if(!word.equals(" "))
    {
      words[pos]=word;
      freqs[pos]=1;
      return true;
    }
    return true;
  }
  static int sequentialSearch(String[] array, int from, int to, String searchValue)
  {
    assert 0<=from&&0<=to : "Invalidbounds";
    assert array!=null : "Array shouldbeinitialized";
    if(from>to)
      return to;
    int position=from;
    while(position<to&&(!array[position].equals(searchValue)))
      position++;
    return position;
  }
  static void displayFrequencies(int nr, String[] words, int[] freqs)
  {
    assert nr>=0&&words!=null&&freqs!=null;

    for(int i=0;i<nr;i++)
    {
      System.out.println(words[i]+" "+freqs[i]);
    }
  }
  static void displayWords(int nr, String[] words, int[] freqs)
  {
    assert nr>=0&&words!=null&&freqs!=null;

    for(int i=0;i<nr;i++)
    {
      System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
  }

  static int findAndCountWord(Scanner scanner, String[] words, String word)
  {
    assert words!=null;
    int wordCount=0;
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
      for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
      {
        if(word.equals(words[i]))
        {
          wordCount++;
        }
      }
    }
    return wordCount;
  }
}
```

Here is another sample which I use as the moment:

```
'Well!' thought Alice to herself, 'after such a fall as this, I shall
think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at
home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top
of the house!' (Which was very likely true.)

Down, down, down. Would the fall NEVER come to an end! 'I wonder how
many miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud. 'I must be getting
somewhere near the centre of the earth. Let me see: that would be four
thousand miles down, I think--' (for, you see, Alice had learnt several
things of this sort in her lessons in the schoolroom, and though this
was not a VERY good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there
was no one to listen to her, still it was good practice to say it over)
'--yes, that's about the right distance--but then I wonder what Latitude
or Longitude I've got to?' (Alice had no idea what Latitude was, or
Longitude either, but thought they were nice grand words to say.)
```

Comment: if this is or your homework, I would hope you're not cheating. but you could use this site to help https://www.regextester.com/97778
You should try using \w and \d instead of using a range of values.

Comment: Here's a hint.  `\b` matches a word boundary.  Use it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Here’s a hint for you: a word boundary exists after "y" and before "b" in "jury-box"

Comment: Oh, you're kidding!  OK, I withdraw my hint.

Answer (score 0):

Use whitespace, *or* punctuation with adjacent whitespace/start/end, asserted using look-arounds:

```
"\\s|\\W+(?=\\s)|(?<=\\s)\\W+|^\\W+|\\W+$"
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/OJcr61ooEf).

`\W` means non-word, and word is any letter or digit (or the underscore, but that shouldn’t cause you a problem).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It works fine for such words.  It doesn't match the internal apostrophe.

Comment: Note that there are edge cases like `"'tis"` and `"o'"` that break your plan.

Comment: You might get into trouble with things like _Charles' books_ but I don't see how to work around that.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem true. at that point you’d need to parse the semantic to figure out if the apostrophe was a speech delimiter or a possessive - way beyond what regex can do.

Comment: Why not just require at least one whitespace? E.g. `\\W*\\s+\\W*|^\\W+|\\W+$`? That way it can also do text like `He said: "Hello"`

Comment: @Joakim don’t know what you mean. the exclamation mark is a negation there, not a literal.

Comment: @Bohemian♦ thanks for your answer, it looks much better already. One question, what does that '\\' do? And what is the difference with a single '\'?

Comment: @sam double backslash is how you code a single literal backslash in Java. That single backslash is then an escape inside the regex. A single backslash in a String literal is the escape character, eg `"\t"` is a tab character.

Comment: Thanks. If I implement it the way you wrote it, still a lot of words are printed ending with a dot, comma etc. How should I add a pattern of ending characters which I want to exclude?

Comment: @sam show your code and sample input and we can help. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added it, with an example which I'm using at the moment

Comment: @sam I amended the regex by adding `+` to the terms. “+” means one *or more*. See live demo link, which shows it matching delimiters correctly.